# LARAVEL 5 : Validate JSON data for uniqueness before saving in database

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am fairly new to Laravel.

I am trying to fetch some user data from a remote location as JSON. Here's the code in my Controller to fetch the JSON data.

```
public function fetch()
{       
    $url = 'http://example.com'; //fetching data as JSON
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $this->save($json);
}
```

I have a User Model class which corresponds to my users table. The email and phone columns are set as unique in the database table.

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone'
    ];  

}
```

The Save function in the same Controller

```
private function save($json)
{
   foreach ($json as $key => $value) 
   {
      $user = User::create([                
         'name'     =>  $value['name'],
         'email'    =>  $value['email'],
         'phone'    =>  $value['phone']
     ]);
   }
}
```

The save works fine as long as the email and phone are unique. If not, it throws a nasty QueryException

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry...

Is there a way to validate the data for uniqueness before trying to save in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-validate-json-data-for-uniqueness-before-saving-in-database) using Validator class

Answer (score 0):

i think my answer will help other people coming after[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTh2G.png)
in class validation form request if you use it
you can use function as call back function
at Laravel form request
like that
and also you can validate json value uniqueness

see exmple at link image its very easy to check validation json uniqueness in database

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30711968)